# Is empty enum ( enum{}; ) portable?

Tags: c++

```
class Test
{
  enum{};
  ...
};
```

Is this empty enum definition portable? Compiles in gcc and and msvc.

Comment: What are you using it for?

Comment: In a macro that may have an empty parameter

Comment: That not just an empty enum, it's an anonymous empty enum, which, as said in the other answers, is ill-formed becase it declares nothing. So, empty enums are valids, which aren't valid are anonymous empty enums. You could declare both `enum {A}` and  `enum e {}`, which are valid declarations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

such an enum is specifically listed in clause 7 paragraph 3 of the C++ standard as
ill-formed. gcc does not accept it. there was a bug fix for this in gcc:

http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=29018

Comment: I'd missed that.  The grammar allows the form, but in the chapter header, there is a specific prohibition of, in effect, any declaration which doesn't declare either a type or an entity (variable, function or reference).  And gives precisely this case as an example.

Comment: @Nawaz The paragraph cited by WeaselFox is present in C++98, C++03 and C++11, unchanged and with this exact example.

Answer (score 7):

According to the following snippet from the c++ standard we can deduce that it's indeed a valid statement:

> **7.2**/1 **Enumeration declarations** (C++03)
> ...
>   enum-specifier:
>   
>        enum *identifier<sub>opt</sub>* { *enumerator-list<sub>opt</sub>* }

Note that both the *identifier* and the *enumerator-list* are optional, and therefor a statement as `enum {}` is valid (if you ask the standard).

---

**But doesn't the standard also say that empty declarations are ill-formed?**

Yes, and there is even an example of `enum { };` in the below snippet from the standard.

> **7**/3 **Specifiers** (C++03)
>
> In these cases and whenever a class-specifier or enum-specifier is
>   present in the decl-specifier-seq, the identifiers in these specifiers
>   are among the names being declared by the declaration (as class-
>   names, enum-names, or enumerators, depending on the syntax).
>
> In such cases, and except for the declaration of an unnamed bit-field
>   (9.6), **the *decl-specifier-seq* shall introduce one or more names into
>   the program, or shall redeclare a name introduced by a previous
>   declaration.**
>
> *Example [

```
 enum { };          // ill-formed
 typedef class { }; // ill-formed
```

> *end example]

---

**Conclusion**

The statement seems to be ill-formed after a careful look at the standard, though compilers are written by humans - and humans tend to make mistakes and sometimes overlook things.

---

**TL;DR** You should not use an empty declaration such as `enum { };`, even though it compiles

Comment: But as  WeaselFox pointed out, there is a general semantic constraint,
for __all__ declarations, in §7/3, that effectively bans declarations
that don't declare anything.  One of the examples it gives is `enum
{};`.

Comment: @JamesKanze answer updated, thank you for the heads up I completely forgot about `7.1/3`.

Comment: @refp I'd missed it too, until WeaselFox pointed it out.  (And the
section is §7/3, not §7.1/3.)

Comment: @refp: 7 (Declarations) and 7.1 (Specifiers) are different sections. 7.1/3 is a note about some specifiers which imply `int`.

Comment: @interjay true, haha I'm too tired for this right now.. been sick for a few days (excuses excuses excuses). post edited.